Elastic Search 8.13 - Unable to Launch New Service
I'm trying to install SonarQube:10.6.0-Community Image as docker container in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS as part of Suite of Applications as docker container to run local Jenkins Workloads. My Services Include Jenkins 2.440.1,Sonans NexusRepo(3.70.0-03), Vault.
I deploy the above all of the services as Jenkins Compose File. The issue I'm facing is that I'm not able to access Sonar Qube Web Portal. Eventhough my Container is coming up properly and stablised. On Examining Logs I found error realted to Elastic Search as follows which is causing Sonar Qube Portal issues( I think !!). I trired to tweak params in Ubuntu in sysctl i.e fs.inotify.max_user_watches and vm.max_map_count.
But none of these resolve my error releated to elastic search.
Elastic Search Error :
WARN  es[][o.e.c.s.ClusterApplierService] failed to notify ClusterStateListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: unable to launch a new watch service
    at org.elasticsearch.common.file.AbstractFileWatchingService.startWatcher(AbstractFileWatchingService.java:159) ~[elasticsearch-8.13.4.jar:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.file.MasterNodeFileWatchingService.clusterChanged(MasterNodeFileWatchingService.java:67) ~[elasticsearch-8.13.4.jar:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterApplierService.callClusterStateListener(ClusterApplierService.java:560) ~[elasticsearch-8.13.4.jar:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterApplierService.callClusterStateListeners(ClusterApplierService.java:546) ~[elasticsearch-8.13.4.jar:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterApplierService.applyChanges(ClusterApplierService.java:505) ~[elasticsearch-8.13.4.jar:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterApplierService.runTask(ClusterApplierService.java:429) ~[elasticsearch-8.13.4.jar:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterApplierService$UpdateTask.run(ClusterApplierService.java:154) ~[elasticsearch-8.13.4.jar:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:917) ~[elasticsearch-8.13.4.jar:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.runAndClean(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:217) ~[elasticsearch-8.13.4.jar:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.run(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:183) ~[elasticsearch-8.13.4.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: User limit of inotify instances reached or too many open files
    at sun.nio.fs.LinuxWatchService.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystem.newWatchService(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.file.AbstractFileWatchingService.startWatcher(AbstractFileWatchingService.java:137) ~[elasticsearch-8.13.4.jar:?]
    ... 12 more
2024.09.12 10:39:43 WARN  es[][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] flood stage disk watermark [95%] exceeded on [ktTU66ORQ6eMycWtaYyjgA][sonarqube][/opt/sonarqube/data/es8] free: 9.3gb[4%], all indices on this node will be marked read-only
2024.09.12 10:40:13 WARN  es[][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] flood stage disk watermark [95%] exceeded on [ktTU66ORQ6eMycWtaYyjgA][sonarqube][/opt/sonarqube/data/es8] free: 9.3gb[4%], all indices on this node will be marked read-only

SonarQube Log :
024.09.12 10:39:05 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[ELASTICSEARCH] from [/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch]: /opt/java/openjdk/bin/java -Xms4m -Xmx64m -XX:+UseSerialGC -Dcli.name=server -Dcli.script=./bin/elasticsearch -Dcli.libs=lib/tools/server-cli -Des.path.home=/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch -Des.path.conf=/opt/sonarqube/temp/conf/es -Des.distribution.type=tar -cp /opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch/lib/*:/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch/lib/cli-launcher/* org.elasticsearch.launcher.CliToolLauncher
2024.09.12 10:39:05 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running

I tried tweaking params for sysctl and tried to increase java heap size param for Javaopts config

Hey Kalyan, flood stage disk watermark [95%] exceeded on [ktTU66ORQ6eMycWtaYyjgA][sonarqube][/opt/sonarqube/data/es8] free: 9.3gb[4%] indicates that the disk is too full to continue with the current settings.

Hey @IanGabes Thanks for your response. I think you are right.  As the Error is misleading to start with. But having looked at your response and investigating my disk usage I found that it is running at above 90%, Tried to clear some unwanted docker overlays files and un used volumes and images. I managed to reclaim back some space back which kind of resolves watermark error. But still Elastic Search Error mentioned above is still occurring. Good News I can access the portal at port 9000 but could not able to login with default creds.. Anythoughts?

see here
